# Programmatically check whether CallKit API is supported on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, callkit

My VOIP has to support the legacy behaviour for iOS versions < 10.0 since the CallKit API is supported from the iOS version >= 10.0.

How can I programmatically check whether the CallKit is supported or not without using IF_DEF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Objective-C, read the [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i).

For Swift, use [`#available`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID523).

Answer (score 0):

For objective-C use

BOOL callKitAvailable = [CXCall class] != nil;